# How to determine where two method call hierarchies intersect?

Tags: java

Given two completely different method calls, in two completely different classes, in the Java Programming Language and all their potential sub calls.

The goal would be to find the common intersect between the two call hierarchies.

It would also help if I knew the right terminology behind this as well but the best I can come up with is method intersection.

EDIT - Diagram:

[image]

Comment: So you want to know if `methodA` calls `methodB`?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information, if you had it?

Comment: @BrianGoetz - given an extremely large code base it would give me a yes/no answer as to whether or not a specific feature (tied to a java function) exists and is called in another feature within the same code base.

Comment: @Makoto - consider infinite sub method calls in a tree hierarchy - if and where any potential possibilities intersect for the given methods.

Comment: In the "Java Class 3" box of your diagram, should _Call to Java Class 3: Method_A()_ actually say _Call to Java Class 1: Method_A()_? If not, then what does the arrow line between Class 1 and Class 3 represent?

Comment: @andrewjames - fixed - rushing to make sure I clarify this post.

Comment: If I'm trying to understand a complicated Java class, I make a tree diagram showing the names of all the methods, with the names of called methods under the calling method.  I make the diagram by hand, although my Eclipse IDE gives me a call hierarchy for a given method.

Comment: @Cody But, you're just restating the question as an answer.  What will having this information enable, that you can't do now?   (Also, it seems likely that almost every Java method will call one of Object::equals, Object::hashCode, Object::toString -- so the answer will almost always be "yes".  Again, I think you are deep in an XY problem.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz - I disagree but maybe don't understand your question - finding a way to avoid manually taking hours worth of time to review every call of a sub-function to see where the two classes intersect. The call hierarchy tool in an IDE becomes limited when trying to do a use case like this.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - I agree - this is normally what I do too - however I was looking to see conceptually if there is a faster way to do this without doing it by hand.

Comment: It's not a matter of speed.  If you're trying to understand a class, it will take time.  The hand creating of a tree diagram is but a moment in the time needed to understand (and possibly refactor) a class.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have an actual problem you're trying to solve, but you've incorrectly generalized it to a much harder problem.  Let's take the only-slightly-simpler problem of "given a method A, what code might it call (directly or indirectly)."  (If you could solve that, then you could run it for A and B, and take the intersection.)

This problem is already too hard to solve practically, without introducing some constraints which might well be too severe for your situation.  Here are some sources of complexity in this problem that you could get mired in for years.

- Hierarchy-driven polymorphism.  A method may have a call to `list.get(x)`.  But `List` is an interface, and there are many implementations.  Are we to include "any code that might get called from any implementation of `List`?"
- Data-driven polymorphism.  Java has lambdas.  Suppose I have a `List<Runnable>`, and I stick various lambdas in it (`list.put(x -> Foo.bar(x))`), and then I iterate the list and execute the lambdas (`list.forEach(r -> r.run())`).  Do I have to track all the code that might create a lambda that might eventually get put in that list?
- Dynamic code loading.  Java is dynamically linked and can dynamically load classes (and, can dynamically generate classes and load them.)  Do we include the universe of all possibly-loadable classes?

As you can see, this spirals out of control very quickly (and I haven't gotten to any of the crazy stuff yet), to the point where your only recourse is "run the program and measure coverage."  Which I don't think is what you're trying to do.

I suspect what you're really trying to do is identify techniques that might help you reason about the effects of calling a given method -- will it do IO, or mutate certain variables, or throw an exception?  If so, that's a very different question than the one you've stated.  (This is generally called an XY problem; you want to do X, you imagine Y might be the way to do it, and then you ask about Y.)

Comment: You are very right about the spiraling - I'd envision that you'd have to include a whitelist of sorts for optimization. In regards to dynamic class loading - that's an issue that I don't think will come into play here for more tightly coupled code but is definitely a concept that exists in the codebase I'm attempting to true/false confirm a feature call on.

The concept here is very experimental and I appreciate your well detailed and thought out answer here.